# Pasos en el grid del eje x en gráfico con seaborn

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

Quisiera saber cómo puedo definir los pasos de división del eje X de un gráfico de dispersión de puntos en Python para que éste siempre muestre el grid en pasos de una unidad. Para el gráfico estoy utilizando seaborn con el siguiente código:

```
from jnpr.junos import Device
import re
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from itertools import chain
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

dates_unique = list(set(data_per_x.DATE.to_list()))   
    for i in dates_unique:
        data=data_per_x[data_per_x.DATE==i]
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,9), dpi= 80)
        sns.set(style="whitegrid")
        sns.stripplot(x="HOUR", y="SEVERITY", size=data['COUNTS']*0.05, data=data, ax=ax)
        plt.title(i, fontsize=22)
        plt.show()
```

La idea del código es mostrar gráficamente la cantidad de categorias de Logs de un equipo por hora.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro conseguir que el eje x me muestre las horas por unidad (0, 1, 2, 3, ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que `stripplot` se usa cuando al menos uno de los ejes son datos categóricos, voy a asumir que solo el eje <kbd>y</kbd> son categóricos. Si es así, puedes hacer uso de a[`axis.xaxis.set_major_locator`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axis.Axis.set_major_locator.html) de matplotlib para especificar la frecuencia de las marcas del eje <kbd>x</kbd> mediante [`matplotlib.ticker`](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html).

Dado que no tengo tus datos, voy a usar el propio ejemplo de la documentación de seaborn para que sea reproducible:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,13), dpi= 80)
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
sns.stripplot(x="total_bill", y="day", data=tips, linewidth=1)
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si especificamos que las marcas tenga una frecuencia de una unidad:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style="whitegrid")
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20,13), dpi= 80)
sns.set(style="whitegrid")
sns.stripplot(x="total_bill", y="day", data=tips, linewidth=1)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias, funciona bien.